# How to create a valid CFFI representation of a numpy array of unicode strings?

Tags: python, python-cffi

I have a `numpy.ndarray` named `values` containing  `numpy.unicode_` strings and I have a C function `foo` that consumes an array of C-strings. There is a CFFI wrapper interface for `foo`.

So I have tried to do something like this

```
p = ffi.from_buffer("char**", values)
```

and also

```
p = ffi.from_buffer("char*[]", values)
```

This doesn't give any errors in CFFI. But once I run the code it crashes in the C implementation of `foo` and indeed when I look at the pointers they look bad:

```
(gdb) p d
$1 = (char **) 0x1f978a50
(gdb) p d[0]
$2 = 0x7300000061 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x7300000061>
```

I am on a 64 bit architecture.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work like you are trying to do, because the numpy array contains pointers to Python objects (all of type `str`), I believe.  In any case, it is something else than a raw array of `char *` pointers to the UTF8-encoded versions of the strings.

I think there is no automatic way to do the conversion.  You need to do the loop over the items manually, and manually convert all the strings to `char[]` arrays, and make sure they are all kept alive long enough.  This should do it:

```
items = [ffi.new("char[]", x.encode('utf-8')) for x in values]
p = ffi.new("char *[]", items)
# keep 'items' alive as long as you need 'p'
```

or, if all you need is to call a C function that expects a `char **` argument, you can rely on the automatic Python-list-to-C-array conversion, as long as every item of the Python list is a `char *`:

```
items = [ffi.new("char[]", x.encode('utf-8')) for x in values]
lib.my_c_function(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `numpy` is not really representing an array of C strings as `char*[]`. But it is more like a big single `char[]` in which all strings are occurring using strides equal to `.itemsize` which in the case of an array of strings is the size of the biggest occurring string. Shorter strings are padded with zero bytes. And the optional first argument `cdecl` in `ffi.from_buffer` is not involved in any rigorous type checking on the received underlying buffer/memory view. It is the responsibility of the programmer to know the correct type of the perceived buffer/memory view.

The `cdecl` argument will provide type safety when for instance used in conjunction with calls to other `CFFI` wrapped functions.

The way I solved this is by allocating a separate array of char pointers in cffi

```
t = ffi.new('char*[]', array_size)
```

Next massage the numpy array a bit to guarantee that each string is null terminated.
then to implement some logic in Python (or C and then wrapped in CFFI if performance is required)
to point each member in the char*[] array to its corresponding string in the numpy array.